# c printf function dynamic type determination

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, runtime, printf

I am trying to implement a generic stack in c using void pointer to point to the data. the structure looks like this

```
struct record{
  void* data;
  struct record* previousRecord; 
};
```

where void pointer data is a pointer to the data a stack position will hold. If I implement a push function like this

```
struct record* push(struct record* tos, void* data){
  struct record* newtos = (struct record*)malloc(sizeof(struct record));
  newtos->data = data;
  newtos->previousRecord = tos;
  return newtos;
}
```

and push a couple of integer pointers and string pointers into the stack, is there any way I can print the values referenced by these pointers. My problem is that I have to specify the data type of value to print in the code if I use a printf function but the values stored in the stack can only be determined at run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With address how would you know the type of data, it can be string or an integer address:

But you can keep an extra field in your `record` definition about type of value stored in `data part`, like below:

```
typedef enum { STRING, INT, CHAR} type;
struct record{
  type t;
  void* data;
  struct record* previousRecord; 
};
```

and write a common print function :

```
int print(struct record  *r){  

  switch(r->t){
     case CHAR:     return printf("%c", *((char*)(r->data)));
     case INT:      return printf("%d", *((int*)r->data));        
     case STRING:   return printf("%s", (char*)r->data);        
     default:       return printf("Error");
  }
}
```

[Here is a **Project/A book**](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) that can be very helpful to write generic code in C.

Comment: I don't think your print function is correct. `r->data` is a pointer, never a char or int. You need eg. `*(char*)r->data` in the CHAR case.

Comment: @Anonymous Yes you are correct ...And I am using %s and %c with same form r->data that wrong! ..Thanks Anonymous! ...Can you please check again (because complex typecast included)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to print a data in the correct format, you *must* know what is its type.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum datatype
{
  DATATYPE_STRING, DATATYPE_INTEGER
};

struct record
{
  enum datatype type;
  void *data;
  struct record *next;
};

void print_record(struct record *p)
{
  switch (p->type)
  {
    case DATATYPE_STRING:
      printf("%s\n", (char *)p->data);
      break;
    case DATATYPE_INTEGER:
      printf("%d\n", *(int *)p->data);
      break;
  }
}
```